# How to send read txtFile content to client in Node.js with vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get some data in a txt file from my server.js file, but I'm not sure how to obtain that data.

server.js:

```js
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    const { method, url } = req;
    res.status = 200;
    res.setHeader("Content-type", "text/json");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");

    if (url === "/view-stuff" && method === "GET") {
        console.log("RECIEVED GET REQ");
        let stuffReturned= fs.readFile("string.txt", (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            } else {
                return data;
            }
        });
        res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
        res.write(stuffReturned);
    }     
res.end();
});
```

client.js:

```js
function getStuffToview(){
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "//localhost:1000//view-stuff", true);
    request.addEventListener("load", function () {
        try {
            console.log(this.responseText);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(request.status);
        }
    });
    request.send();
});
}
```

I know it's working to some degree, because my console is logging "RECEIVED GET REQ". However, right after that's logged I get this error:

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received undefined.

I tried `res.send(stuffReturned)` instead, but it just says "res.send(stuffReturned)" is not a function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I think you want to use `fs.readFileSync()`.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, that worked for me, what's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`fs.readFile()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/fs.html#fsreadfilepath-options-callback) is an asynchronous function for reading file contents. It does not return anything.

[`fs.readFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/fs.html#fsreadfilesyncpath-options) is a synchronous read function. It returns the contents of the file being read.

A difference between the two is that `fs.readFileSync` blocks other operations until the read is done and content is returned, while `fs.readFile` does this asynchronously, allowing other operations to be done while reading the file in chunks.

Node.JS also includes Promise versions of file system methods, such as [`filehandle.readFile()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/fs.html#filehandlereadfileoptions). You can use these like so:

```js
const fs = require("fs/promises");

(async () => {
  const stuffReturned = await fs.readFile("string.txt");
  console.log(stuffReturned); // the contents of the file
});
```